# CIImage with CGImage memory grow up

Tags: ios, cgimage, ciimage

I'm creating a photo slideshow app. 
My app flow : 
user select photo assets > (over 100+)
load images from assets > (display image size)
set imageView image or add CIFilter to image and slides

Question : 
When I create  CIImage Object from CGImage , the memory is growing up so fast and if the image count over 100+, the app crash.
But it's strange that I remove the create code, the app works fine.

Can anybody help me ?

more code :

```
- (void)loadDisplayImagesWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *images))completion {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("PhotosEditViewController_loadImageQueue", nil), ^{

        __block NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray array];
        __block int handleCount = 0;
        __weak PhotosEditViewController *weakSelf = self;

        for (PHAsset *asset in self.photoAssets) {
            [KPPhotoManager requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:self.contentView.frame.size completeBlock:^(UIImage *image) {

                [images addObject:image];

                @autoreleasepool {
                    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage]];//memory growing up
                }
            }];
        }
    });
}
```

// KPPhotoManager

```
+ (void)requestImageForAsset:(PHAsset*)asset targetSize:(CGSize)size completeBlock:(void (^)(UIImage *image))completeBlock
    {
        [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:size contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:[self createImageRequestOptions] resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable result, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
            completeBlock(result);
        }];
    }
```

Comment: why you call 100 time create image ?

Comment: do a photo slideshow, maybe 0.1s display one image

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project copying your code. I increased the number of calls to 10000 and inspecting the memory all looks well. It does jump a bit but does not inflate.

I also tried to force image load using:

```
for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image2.png"]];
        [self createFilterImageWithImage:image];
    }
}
```

and it still does not inflate the memory.

How are you inspecting your memory leak? Are you looking at the memory consumption? Are there any specifics in your project or file such as having disabled ARC?

Comment: try to load hd image like 1920x1920

Comment: if you try to load HD image then your app crush so display like thumbnail

Comment: @郑晓航 I used 1513 × 1087 which should be more then enough.

Comment: @MaticOblak I create new project and it work fine, but the same code in another project lead to memory growing up fast.

Comment: @郑晓航 So this should lead to the fact that the code you posted is not what causes the memory issue. Do a bit more analytics on your code and try to update your question with some additional information.